# Two ways of linking to static libraries

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, ld, static-linking, unix-ar

Here are a couple of ways to use functions from a static library, built with **ar** (i.e. `libSOMTEHING.a`):

```
ld -o result myapp.o  -Lpath/to/library -lname 
ld -o result myapp.o  path/to/library/libname.a
```

Since we omit any dynamic libraries from the command line, this should build a static executable.

What are the differences? For example, are the whole libraries linked in the executable, or just the needed functions? In the second example, does switching the places of the lib and the object file matter?

(PS: some non-GNU `ld` linkers require all options like `-o` to be before the first non-option filename, in which case they'd only accept `-L... -lname` before `myapp.o`)

Comment: 1) "-Lpath/to/library" lets you find multiple libraries in "path/to/library"; hard-coding the .a path doesn't.  2) if the .o requires modules in the .a, then the library should come *afterwards*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line, a search for a dynamic library (libname.so) occurs before the static library (libname.a) within a directory.  Also, the standard lib path is also searched for libname.*, not just /path/to/library.

From "man ld"

> On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for
>   files other than libnamespec.a. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS
>   systems, ld will search a directory for a library called
>   libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a.  (By
>   convention, a ".so" extension  indicates a shared library.)

The second line forces the linker to use the static library at path/to/lib.

If there is no dynamic library built (libname.so), and the only library available is path/to/library/libname.a, then the two lines will produce the same "result" binary.

Comment: Suppose there is no .so library. Then the binaries will be the same in the sense that no extra functions will be linked in one of the invocations as compared to the other. Correct?